# Saving data in Win32 TIB

Tags: c, windows, winapi

The Thread-Information Block should be widely known, and can be used to access a few important information. But can I use it to save data?

I've seen the structure has a slot for an arbitrary pointer at offset `14h` (x86) / `28h` (x86-64).

Can I use this pointer to point to my own thread structure from my own scheduler? Or does it get overridden by something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`TlsAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801(v=vs.85).aspx) function to allocate thread local storage. Each TLS index can save a pointer-sized value, so you can use a TLS slot to point to a larger allocated data structure if needed.

See [Using Thread Local Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686991(v=vs.85).aspx) for an example.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this solution. This could potentially spawn issues since the user can override this by `TlsFree()`'ing the slot.

Comment: The user? Who is this user you refer to? They are writing code in your program without your knowledge? You have to make them promise not to free your TLS slots. Just as you'd need to make them promise not to write to the TIB. Use TLS. The TIB is private.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes. I can't use TLS since it requires me to do assumptions which might not be true. I can't use an index to access it, meaning I would have to use the TIB to access the TLS anyway, and I would have to assume the user didn't replaced my entry points and wrote something in the first TLS slot.

Comment: Utter nonsense. You can perfectly well use TLS as the rest of us do. On the other hand, you seem to have already decided that TIB is the correct solution so why are you even asking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not utter nonsense. I'm writing a replacement for Microsoft C runtime libraries and do not want to take up space of the TLS from the user. I'm also not asking for an alternative, I'm asking whether it's safe to use this specific TIB field, which from every documentation I could find points to being reserved for user data. The question is, who is the user? The Microsoft CRT? I'm not using that. Some Win32 method? Or can I use it without worrying? Alternatively, 10h (x86) is a pointer to "FiberData", since I have my own Fibers, is that save?

Comment: You can certainly use TLS. You allocate a slot and use it. Simple as that. It's what the rest of us do. If you start hacking at the TIB then don't complain when you find it changes in a future release of Windows.

Comment: Neither you @DavidHeffernan, nor Jonathan Potter provided an answer to my question. I still don't write a user application, but a system library. What's next, will you tell me that I can't use an identifier with two leading underscores, because they're reserved for system libraries? I am the system library. I acknowledge it might break in a future release, so does Microsoft's own libraries. Microsoft hasn't changed the NT block of the TIB in over 20y, I hightly doubt they'll do that now.

Comment: Microsoft's runtime uses TLS, so I don't see why yours can't.

Comment: You can allocate a TLS index and use it. Once you have allocated the index, nobody else gets to use that same index until you decide to free it. You are standing on top of Win32. May as well take advantage of that.

Comment: Ok, @DavidHeffernan. Convinced. I'm going to avoid touching the TIB. A question remains, how can I access the TLS structure without accessing the TIB or an index? I can't pass an index around, it has to be globally available.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that you've set you mind against TLS for reasons that I cannot imagine. You are desperate to know whether or not slot 14h of the TIB is used by anything else. Well, maybe it is, maybe it is not. It all depends on what is loaded into your process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan See my comment.

Comment: What's wrong with using a global to store an index?

Comment: @HarryJohnston The global would have to be thread-local, too? I can't assume each thread has the same index, can I?

Comment: Passing an index around is one way. I would expect that your system could be designed in such a way as to support that. Still, the index needs to be stored somewhere or other. Typically you'd store it in a global variable. You'd call `TlsAlloc` when your module is loaded, and `TlsFree` when it is unloaded.

Comment: Yes, each thread uses the same index. A global is what you want, for the index. Follow the links in the answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Doh. Obviously each thread has to use the same index. I was confused for a second. Ok, I'll use TLS. Thank's a lot. Excuse me for my initial stubbornness.